# Powershell start-process command is not running in detached mode with github action

Tags: powershell, github-actions

I am trying to run following command using github action. Start-Process exits as soon as github action step is over.

```
 - name: Run test
    shell: powershell
    run: |
      start-Process -FilePath "C:\Program Files (x86)\SmartBear\TestExecute 14\x64\Bin\TestExecute.exe" -ArgumentList "`"C:\Automation.mds`" /project:`"Automation`" /unit:Main /routine:Main /r /SilentMode /e /version:1.00.04"
```

However, if I run the same command manually from powershell it works fine.

Any suggestion/help is much appreciated.

Comment: Is there any sort of output from GitHub actions that you can show us?

Comment: Run start-Process -FilePath "C:\Program Files (x86)\SmartBear\TestExecute 14\x64\Bin\TestExecute.exe" -ArgumentList "`"C:\Automation.mds`" /project:`"Automation`" /unit:Main /routine:Main /r /SilentMode /e /version:1.00.04"

  start-Process -FilePath start-Process -FilePath "C:\Program Files (x86)\SmartBear\TestExecute 14\x64\Bin\TestExecute.exe" -ArgumentList "`"C:\Automation.mds`" /project:`"Automation`" /unit:Main /routine:Main /r /SilentMode /e /version:1.00.04"
Output: 
  shell: C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.EXE -command ". '{0}'"